# Potential spring security memory leak

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails, spring-security

I have a grails 3.1.7 project that uses spring security core 3.1.1 and deployed to a tomcat instance (not sure of the tomcat version).

This line appears in the log from time to time:

> 13-Apr-2018 13:31:20.710 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
>   The web application [my-app] created a ThreadLocal with key of
>   type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@6678f8db]) and a value of type
>   [org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse] (value
>   [org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse@159982ef])
>   but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads
>   are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory
>   leak.

I know this is part of tomcats normal operation when [it checks for memory leaks](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) and it seems that most people just choose to ignore it. That is what we have done in the past. This time we were told to 'fix it', but given that the threadlocal variable that leaked is coming from a spring security class, I am not sure what to fix or how to fix it.

So before I embark on a long detour trying to debug this, does anyone know what is going on here? Has anyone else seen this? Is it benign or do I need to do some more digging? What should I tell security to convince them to ignore it?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A memory leak on JVM is usually a performance problem, not a security one. Search security issues for your spring version to see if something similar exists.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz The product is "spring security"; I don't think OP was trying to report a security vulnerability.

Comment: @christopher-schultz agree.

Comment: I've seen the same problem in a similar scenario, as OP description says "when the web application was stopped". In my case the `type` was something else so it's related to ThreadLocal instances not cleanly handled at application stop.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the team that reported the bug did indeed kill the webapp with 'kill -9'. Makes sense that tomcat cleaned up after it.